# Is there any online, html/flash/js based, free C++ editor that can compile code for ubuntu?

Tags: c++, c, linux, compiler-construction

It can be opensource. I need it because I don't want to install virtual machine. So is there any online, html/flash/js based, free C++ (or at least C) compiler that can compile code simulating ubuntu c/c++ compiler and return built executable file to me? I heard that Mozilla had some cool online editors but I don't know if they have compilation options.

Comment: Why does it need to be online?

Comment: Writing a C++ compiler in Javascript would be quite fun... NOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepad](http://codepad.org)  allows you to compile and run code snippets, which is good to quickly test ideas and/or share code quickly among friends; in no way it substitutes a good editor and programming environment.

Plus, in any non-trivial project you need external libraries, I don't know how you would be able to deal with that.

Just get over your laziness and install that virtual machine! I tried [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) recently and it's very easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you clearly understand the difference between an editor and a compiler.

An editor cannot compile code.
A compiler doesn't help you to edit code.
An IDE (Integrated Development Environment) incorporates the features of both an editor and a compiler.

Are you asking if anyone knows of an IDE that can compile for Ubuntu?

What platform do you want it to run on?

Comment: Yeah, I was ignoring the "online" bit because it didn't make sense to me. Where is the code kept then? On someone else's server? Or do you upload the code?

Comment: Yes i Idea was keep it on someones else server=)

Comment: You're obviously a very generous chap to give your code away so freely ;) Now I understand the question. I'm unfamiliar with the idea, so didn't really understand it before.

Comment: I think I understand why Kabumbus would want this, I've ran into situation like this before. I'm on a CR48 and sometimes I badly wanted to test out a piece of code but have no access to the desktop pc, an online c/c++ (or whatever) editor that can compile on the server and return result is better than nothing :)